# Certificate issue\ Fail to connect MQTT broker (AWS) with TLS\SSL by paho-mqtt in Python

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, mqtt, paho

I have verified the configuration in MQTT spy, it works great, can publish and receive msg. But when I tried to connect the same broker with the same arguments in Python by paho-mqtt, it cannot work cause by the TSL\SSL certification process.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WIJo.png)

```
import ssl
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

HOST = "iot-qa.paxafe.com"
PORT = 8883
ca_cert = "C:\workspace\\atd530test\QPST\CA_files\\amazon.cer"
certfile = "C:\workspace\\atd530test\QPST\MQTT_Spy\CA_files\client.pem.crt"
keyfile = "C:\workspace\\atd530test\QPST\MQTT_Spy\CA_files\client.pem.key"

def on_connnect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected to MQTT")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic + " :" + str(msg.payload))

client = mqtt.Client()
client.tls_set(ca_certs=ca_cert, certfile=certfile, keyfile=keyfile, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, ciphers= None)
client.tls_insecure_set(True)
client.on_connect = on_connnect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(host = HOST, port = PORT)
client.loop_forever()
```

And got `ssl.SSLError: [X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:4140)`

So I copied the content from `amazon.cer`, and generate `amazon.pem`

then, change the ca_certs to `ca_cert = "C:\workspace\\atd530test\QPST\CA_files\\amazon.pem"`

But, still failed, it shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/41344/Desktop/mqttTest.py", line 27, in <module>
    client.connect(host = HOST, port = PORT)
  File "C:\Users\41344\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 914, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "C:\Users\41344\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 1073, in reconnect
    sock.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\41344\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)
```

Also, I tried some solutions:

add `ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context`, not work.

add `client = mqtt.Client(protocol=MQTTv31)`, not work

delete `cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, ciphers= None`, not work

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your local CA,

```
pip install -U certifi
```

Comment: Thanks balun, but still not work.
Got the same results 
`self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)`